# React Contact form get 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, email

Right now, I'm making a portfolio website, everything works as it is supposed to in my machine, but when I deploy it to the live serve, in dies. When I submit the contact form and refresh the page, it says GET 404 - NOT FOUND in the browser console. The thing is, the url stays the same but as soon as it refreshes dies. Even tho that url path DOES exist. I'm using emailjs. Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import './contactForm.css';
import { Footer } from '../../containers';

import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

// import axios from 'axios';

const ContactForm = () => {
     //const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
    //  const [recipient_email, setEmail] = useState("");
    //  const [name, setName] = useState("");
    //  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

// ----------------------------Emailjs----------------------------
     const form = useRef();

     const sendEmail = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
   
       emailjs.sendForm('service_ebesa9d', 
                        'template_846mobc', 
                        form.current, 
                        '1oviDjIxcKzRsgPPd')

         .then((result) => {
             console.log(result.text);
             console.log("message sent");
             alert("Message sent succesfully");
            //  window.location.reload(false);
         }, (error) => {
             console.log(error.text);
             alert("Oops, something went wrong");
         });
     };
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

    //  function sendMail(){
    //     if(recipient_email && name && message){
    //         axios
    //             .post('http://localhost:5000/send_email', {
    //                 recipient_email,
    //                 name,
    //                 message,
    //             })
    //             .then(() => alert('Message sent succesfuly'))
    //             .catch(() => alert('Oops something went wrong'));
    //         return;
    //     }
    //     return alert('Fill in all the fields to continue');
    //  };

  return (
    <div className='RO__ContactForm' id='contactForm'>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-title'>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <h1>I'm here to help you level up</h1>
        </div>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-content'>
            <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_description'>
                <p>I'm just on click away to help you take your company 
                    to the next level. Fill in the form to share more 
                    details about the project or your favorite movie. 
                    Either way, I'd love to talk.</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <form
                className='RO__ContactForm-content_form'
                ref={form}
                onSubmit={sendEmail}
                >
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_name'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_nameTitle'>
                        <h5>What's your name?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <input 
                        className='RO_ContactForm-content_form_nameInput'
                        type= 'text'
                        id='user_name'
                        // onChange={ (e) => setName(e.target.value) }
                        name='user_name' required 
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_email'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_emailTitle'>
                        <h5>Your email</h5>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_emailInput'
                        type='email'
                        id='user_email'
                        // onChange={ (e) => setEmail(e.target.value) }
                        name='user_email' required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_info'>
                    <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_infoTitle'>
                        <h5>What can I help you with?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <textarea
                        className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_infoContent'
                        id='message'
                        // onChange={ (e) => setMessage(e.target.value) }
                        name='message' required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='RO__ContactForm-content_form_button'>
                    <button 
                        // onClick = {() => sendMail()} 
                        type='submit'
                        value='send'
                    >
                        Submit

                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div className='RO__ContactForm-footer'>
            <Footer  />
        </div>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactForm
```

And here is the code of the paths made for the webpage

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Footer, About, Features, Services, Header, Portfolio, Contact } from './containers';
import { Article, Brand, Cta, Feature, Navbar, ScrollToTop } from './components';
import { Project1, Project2, Project3, Project4, Project5, Project6, Project7 } from './pages'
import { ContactForm } from './pages/contactform';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      
      <Route path='/' element={
        <div className = "App">
          <div className='gradient__bg'>
            <Navbar />
            <Header />
          </div>
          <About />
          <Services />
          <Portfolio />
          <Contact />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      } />
      <Route path='/project1' element = {<Project1 />} />
      <Route path='/project2' element = {<Project2 />} />
      <Route path='/project3' element = {<Project3 />} />
      <Route path='/project4' element = {<Project4 />} />
      <Route path='/project5' element = {<Project5 />} />
      <Route path='/project6' element = {<Project6 />} />
      <Route path='/project7' element = {<Project7 />} />
      <Route path='/contactForm' element = {<ContactForm />} />
      <Route path='/services' element = {<Services />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: did you check if  backend is running/active in server without any errors ?

Comment: This should help you out https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

Comment: I think ContactForm is a default export.. you are using named import.

Comment: You're using React, a SPA framework, so you need to configure your webserver to point all routes to the single page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: That was the issue, whenever I replied my react app, it died! THANKS!